# Manual mock not working in with Jest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Can somebody help me with manual mocking in Jest, please? :)
I try to have Jest use the mock instead of the actual module.

my test:

```
// __tests__/mockTest.js

import ModuleA from "../src/ModuleA"

describe("ModuleA", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock("../src/ModuleA")
    })

    it("should return the mock name", () => {
        const name = ModuleA.getModuleName()
        expect(name).toBe("mockModuleA")
    })
})
```

my code:

```
// src/ModuleA.js
export default {
    getModuleName: () => "moduleA"
}

// src/__mocks__/ModuleA.js
export default {
    getModuleName: () => "mockModuleA"
}
```

I think I followed everything the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) says about manual mocks, but perhaps I'm overlooking something here?
This is my result:

```
Expected value to be:
      "mockModuleA"
Received:
      "moduleA"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Module mocks are hoisted when possible with `babel-jest` transform, so this will result in mocked module:

```
import ModuleA from "../src/ModuleA"
jest.mock("../src/ModuleA") // hoisted to be evaluated prior to import
```

This won't work if a module should be mocked per test basis, because `jest.mock` resides in `beforeEach` function.

In this case `require` should be used:

```
describe("ModuleA", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock("../src/ModuleA")
    })

    it("should return the mock name", () => {
        const ModuleA = require("../src/ModuleA").default;
        const name = ModuleA.getModuleName()
        expect(name).toBe("mockModuleA")
    })
})
```

Since it's not an export but a method in default export that should be mocked, this can also be achieved by mocking `ModuleA.getModuleName` instead of entire module.

Comment: Alright, I see. I was trying with `require` as well but didn't know about the `.default`. The solution worked, tnx :) I also tried it outside of the `beforeEach`, as you explain in the first part and that seems to have worked as well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thanks for explaining how hoisting works in jest

Comment: Nice answer. But I still don't quite understand why `require.default` works but not `import`. I think I'm not understand this sentence `Since it's not an export but a method in default export that should be mocked`

Comment: @drlingyi Mocking with `import` doesn't work because `jest.mock` is evaluated after `import` and cannot affect it, that jest.mock is used in nested scope prevents it from being hoisted. This means that it could be `jest.spyOn(ModuleA, 'getModuleName').mock...` instead of jest.mock. ES module `*` export is readonly by specs and shouldn't be modified directly to mock or spy named exports, but this restriction doesn't apply to `default` object.

Comment: Is it exclusively a `babel-jest` that does hoisting? I thought it was a feature of jest itself.

Comment: @jayarjo Yes. It's impossible for a library to change the way JS works without transforming source code at some point, this is the responsibility of Babel

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not strictly related to the OPs question but google lead me here for a similar issue where `jest.mock('module', () => ({}))` in the root of a file did not work. In my case it was caused by cyclic dependencies. So if jest suddenly starts to ignore calls to `jest.mock()` then you might want to check for cyclic dependencies in your files.

Comment: And what to do with the cyclic dependency?