# Jest unit-testing if super() is called

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, super

I have a custom error class that extends the built-in Error class in Javascript. The problem I came up with is that "super()" method is not checked if it is called or not through my Jest unit testing.

```
export class AppError extends Error {
  public name: string;
  public message: string;
  public status?: number;
  public data?: any;
  constructor(message: string, status?: number, data?: any) {
    super(); <-- this guy!!
    this.name = 'AppError';
    this.status = status || 500;
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to test it? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to unit test your code? One idea is to use "spies" from Jasmine (I usually unit test with Karma+Jasmine).

Comment: @RoboBear I am using Jest.

Comment: It looks like spy can be used on methods such as super.methodA(). And it cannot spy on super() method it self.

Comment: Usually it's better to test for the affect itself, rather than saying "X was called".

Comment: @loganfsmyth Actually, it's better to test both, an additional assertion makes tests stronger and troubleshooting easier. But in this case testing if super() was called is excessive, due to how classes work.

Comment: @supergentle How can spy be used for methods such as super.methodA()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason to check if `super()` is called neither in native ES6 classes nor in classes transpiled with Babel.

Not calling `super` in child class constructor will result in error on class instantiation:

> ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

Babel [provides a safeguard](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EExgKJRTRygzAB2AJpgUVHAN4BQciE5aMUArgjNAAoAlIxas4abmGBRhAbjEBfJoqA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=Node-6.9&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) for that as well:

```
function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }
```

It may be possible to check that parent constructor is called (could be useful to assert `super()` arguments) by mocking child class prototype, something like:

```
let ParentOriginal;
let ParentMock;

beforeEach(() => {
  ParentOriginal = Object.getPrototypeOf(AppError);
  ParentMock = jest.fn();
  Object.setPrototypeOf(AppError, ParentMock);
});

it('..', () => {
  new AppError(...);
  expect(ParentMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
})

afterEach(() => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(AppError, ParentOriginal);
});
```

It's expected to mock `super` in both native classes and classes transpiled with Babel.

But this test is redundant, because missing `super()` will result in error any way. Testing that `AppError` inherits from `Error` is everything that needs be tested here:

```
expect(new AppError(...)).toBeInstanceOf(Error)
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I check the unit testing coverage with jest, and the jest says me that i didn't cover the super() line. then is it a bug from jest?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug and suggest to open an issue regarding that.

Comment: I know this is a year later....will this approach only work with Babel?  I tried this but my super's constructor is still being invoked instead of the mock.  I've tested functionality on the base class and just need to assert that the correct args are being passed to super

Comment: @hvgotcodes As the answer says, this should work with native classes too. The answer mocks a prototype because parent class is Error built-in. If it's custom class and classes are in different modules, you can mock parent's module.

Comment: @estus, do you have an example of that?  Thanks!

Comment: @hvgotcodes By using jest.mock. Something like this question shows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694366/manual-mock-not-working-in-with-jest . I don't have an example with React components but this isn't specific to React. Feel free to post a new question if you will have specific problems with using jest.mock.