# In Jest, is it possible to assert that super.some_function has been called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Is it possible to write `jest` unit test that tests if the `super` function has been called, e.g.

In actual class:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  funk() {
     do_something_specific();
     super.funk();
  }
}
```

or, is there anyway for child class to store references to `super`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest unit-testing if super() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216056/jest-unit-testing-if-super-is-called)

Comment: make function expression and return true if function called

Comment: @juanlumn this is not duplicate of that.