# Why jest mocking doesn't work with ECMAScript Modues?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write unit tests for the payment service.
the payment module as follows:

```
src/modules/payment
├── __mocks__
│   └── payment.service.js
├── payment.controller.js
├── payment.routes.js
├── payment.service.js
└── payment.test.js
```

here is the `package.json` :

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest --forceExit  --maxWorkers=1 \"src/modules/*/.*\\*.test\\.js\"",
   }
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/config/tests/global-test.js"
    ],
    "transform" : {}
  },
```

the test workflow is very simple :

```
// payment.service.js
export default {
    getModuleName: () => "real_data"
}

// __mocks__/payment.service.js
export default {
    getModuleName: () => "test_data"
}

// the test
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'

import paymentService from './payment.service'

jest.mock('./payment.service')

describe("Payment unit tests : ", () => {
    
    it("should return the mock name", () => {
        const name = paymentService.getModuleName()
        expect(name).toBe("test_data")
    })
})
```

I tried doing like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694590/16787671

```
jest.mock('./payment.service', () => ({ __esModule: true, default: { getModuleName: jest.fn() }}))
```

but I failed since I am using nodejs `module`, I also followed the jest ECMAScript Modules guide from here : https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules